# Checking if subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling a bit with this problem:

Is the following set a subspace of ${R}^3$?

$V_3={(a_1,a_2,a_3): (a_2)^2=a_1-a_3}$

So I see that we have the zero-vector. But I'm having a hard time finding out if the subspace is closed under addition due to the square that confuses me. Because if I had two vectors a and b, I would do the following:

$(a_1+b_1), (a_2+b_2), (a_3+b_3)$

But I cant add $(a_2+b_2)$ because the expression I have for them both are squared. What should I do?

Comment: "*due to the square that confuses me*"  That is good that it does, because it should.  The example should be screaming to you that it isn't actually linear.  As for proving it, rather than working with arbitrary variables, since we so strongly suspect that something is wrong, let's use actual numbers.  Can you think of an element of your set?  (*specifically one where $a_2\neq 0$*)  Can you try to add it with itself and see if the result is also in the set?

Comment: So in these problems, I do not have to prove if it is a subspace with a general solution with $a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1,...$ I can just find one counterexample, is that enough?

Comment: Yes, a single counterexample to any one of the vector space axioms will prove that the set is not a vector space.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I think I can handle it from here. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: As for general tips/advice... you will find that the only subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$ are those spaces whose conditions can be written as linear homogeneous systems of equations... linear meaning they only involve sums of scalar multiples of variables like $2a_1-a_2+3a_3$ etc... no funny functions or powers or exponentiation or multiplying by each other or anything allowed.  Homogeneous meaning that they are set equal to zero.  So, if the conditions were $\begin{cases}a_1+a_2-a_3=0\\3a_2+a_3=0\end{cases}$ that would be fine.  Meanwhile $\begin{cases}\sin(a_1)+a_2^2=5\end{cases}$ is definitely not.

Comment: The punchline for this problem is again that squaring $a_2^2$ was not linear.  It boils down to how $(a_2+b_2)^2 = (a_2)^2\color{red}{+2a_2b_2}+(b_2)^2\neq (a_2)^2+(b_2)^2$

Comment: Good points! Thank you so much again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This space is not a subspace.
Consider the two vectors  $a=(2,1,1)$ and $b=( 2,-1,1)$ both are in $v_3$
But their sum is the vector  $ (4,0,2)$ is not in $V_3$ which proves that
$V_3$ is not  a subspace  of $R^3$

Comment: If you have no problem regarding my solution please please vote for it and select it as answer

Comment: Thank your for your help! :)